# HTML rendered in the page looks ok, but the actual result is no

Tags: html, carriage-return

I am developing a page, I am returning data from the server (sharepoint), and displaying it in a paragraph element using $("#Fees").html();

The text should contain carriage return, it shows ok when I view it inside the rendered html itself like the following:

```
    <p id="Fees">Fees should be like the following: 

     Main fees: 
     1- Fee1
     2- Fee2</p>
```

As you can see, inside my paragraph, the carriage return is visible, however, on my page, it's not, as you can see below:

```
Fees should be lik the following: Main fees: 1- Fee1 2- Fee2
```

What should I do? Is it something related to code, or is it a known thing with paragraph tags? I tried it with div tag, and same result. Any idea would be great.

Comment: `is it a known thing with paragraph tags` - no, it's how HTML works ... line breaks (\r \n etc) are just "white space" in HTML documents. you need to use `<br/>` tags or put your text inside a `<pre>` tag, or change the CSS styling of the `<p>` tag to be "like" a `<pre>` tag - and try posting "code" and "resulting text" rather than images of code and resulting text

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX, but why does it show as normal html in the source, but not reflecting on the page?

Comment: because it is normal html ... where line breaks don't matter (like I **just said** )

Comment: in case you want to preserve plain text editor format (blank spaces and newlines) you need to use a <pre>   tag.

Comment: @JaromandaX, I changed it to pre tag, the text is different, the style is different,spaces between lines are different, how can I just make the paragraph tag acts like it ?

Comment: see my answer that I posted before you asked (I saw it coming!!!)

Comment: It is intentional in HTML that all spaces/tabs/newlines are condensed to a single space, to give you the freedom to format your _source_ in whatever way you find convenient and readable without affecting the appearance of the resulting page rendered from that source.  I recommend _not_ setting white-space to `pre` and instead putting in `<br>` tags when you want a line to break at a specific place. In your example, it looks like a _list_ so I would _make it_ a list: `<p>Main fees:</p> <ol> <li>Fee1</li> <li>Fee2</li> </ol>`

Comment: Hi Stephen, I can't control the source as it's data fetched from another system.. so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the following CSS

```
#Fees {
    white-space: pre
}
```

This will make that `<p>` tag behave like a pre tag, without all the other changes a `<pre>` tag has (like font for instance)

Comment: I can accept an answer in 4 minutes :D

Comment: You're brilliant sir

Comment: Cat behaviorists are always good coders

Comment: lol - I forgot I had that there :p

Comment: so the spaces that appear in html but not on the page, are called white spaces? I thought white space is the space I have between words, right?

Comment: No, white space is indeed the space you have between words. The css property "white-space" determines which way the space between words is treated by the browser: pre preserves it (pre-formatted). The default behavior is to strip multiple whitespaces and remove newlines

Comment: Why do people vote down my questions, like my promises question yesterday? What do they expect?

Comment: I guess because there's a similar question on SO.  Though you'd have to know what you're looking for to find it.

Comment: But I don't know what am facing, if I knew the answer, I wouldn't take the time to make a question

Comment: I understand the frustration - some people are quick to vote :p

Comment: many questions on SO are replicated, but people are using the downvote in a wrong way

Comment: @Jacky The downvote button says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" (although I would use the oxford comma: _does not show effort, it is unclear, or not useful_) — these are all a matter of opinion. IMHO a "good" downvoter also comments on what they think needs fixing to improve the question, but I don't think they're using it "in a wrong way". As Jaromanda says, they probably thought you should have been able to find the answer in a previous SO question; but sometimes it's hard to come up with a good search to find those.

Comment: @JaromandaX Hi, can you answer me on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41081380/white-space-pre-adds-extra-padding-any-other-solution

Answer (score 1):

Multiple White Spaces and Line Breaks are read in HTML as a Single White Space. Use the `<pre>` tag if you want to preserve White Space, either that, or use `&nbsp;` to create Non-breaking White Spaces in conjunction with `<br />` to create Block-level line breaks. The CSS solution to make White Space act like the `<pre>` tag would also work: `p{white-space:pre;}`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should translate your line feeds into `<br>` tags before putting your data into the paragraph. Regular line feeds inside html code don't get rendered.

For example, assuming you have your text inside a string before writing it in your `<p>`:

```
yourstring.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, "<br>");
```

Then you move it into the `<p>` tag.