# CSS white-space: pre not working as expected

Tags: html, css

I have text coming back from the server containing carriage return (enter). I asked some people what to do to display this text on multiple lines, and they advised me to use the `white-space: pre`.

Is there any other way to display the text on multiple lines without `white-space: pre`? Or any way to make `pre` act like a paragraph but with multiple lines without having the extra padding?

Here's what I have:

```css
.gallery-Gcontainer {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0;
}
#genericpartTitle,
.content {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.content .sidebar,
.content section {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  border: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.content .sidebar img {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-Gcontainer">
  <div class="header-area">
    <h3 id="genericpartTitle">my page</h3>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <img class="img-sidebar" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/30738/pexels-photo-30738.jpg" />
    </div>
    <section>
      <h5 class="item-title">Welcome to my first page</h5>
      <p style="white-space: pre" class="description">
        Hello, anything will go here, text will come from the server like this, and I need to display it on multiple lines.
      </p>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update:**
Putting: `white-space: pre-line` as suggested in the answers, solved the padding left issue, but still there's a big space in padding-top.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Instead of `white-space: pre` use `white-space: pre-line`.

*From MDN:*

> [**The `white-space`
>   property**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)
>
> The `white-space` property is used to describe how whitespace inside
>   the element is handled.
>
> ***normal*** Sequences of whitespace are collapsed. Newline characters in the source are handled as other whitespace. Breaks lines as
>   necessary to fill line boxes.
>
> ***nowrap*** Collapses whitespace as for `normal`, but suppresses line breaks (text wrapping) within text.
>
> ***pre*** Sequences of whitespace are preserved. Lines are only broken at newline characters in the source and at `<br>` elements.
>
> ***pre-wrap*** Sequences of whitespace are preserved. Lines are broken at newline characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes.
>
> ***pre-line*** Sequences of whitespace are collapsed. Lines are broken at newline characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

Also, the `padding-top` issue you mention isn't really padding. In looking at your code there appears to be at least one line break at the start of the line.

Comment: This worked, then why do I need to use pre? as in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41050367/html-rendered-in-the-page-looks-ok-but-the-actual-result-is-no

Comment: I added the definitions for each value.

Comment: Yes I read that from MDN after you answered me, but it didn't mention anything about paddings

Comment: @Michael_B, try my code, and remove the white-space: pre, you will get rid of the padding

Comment: @Jacky, The `padding-top` issue you mention isn't really padding. There appears to be at least one carriage return at the start of the text.

Answer (score -3):

**If possible then use below javascript  code for CSS .**

```
var ss = " Hello`, anything will go here, text will come from the server like this, and I need to display it on multiple lines.";

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = ss.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
```

or

```
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = ss.replace(/\n/g, '<br>\n');

<p id="test"> </p>
```

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: Because when data append from textarea in Internet explorer to any container like <div> or <p> tag. White space CSS not work with it and it also creates the problem, when we convert HTML to PDF by using lib html2pdf.bundle.js. So here you can replace the new line to <br> tag

Comment: The explanation of your answer belongs _inside_ your answer, not in a comment _under_ your answer.  Please edit your answer, then delete your comment.  Then there will be no need for any comments under your answer.

Answer (score -4):

use "display:block" as your css styling. This should break onto new line.

```
<p style="display: block" class="description">
```